# Meteor 1.0 export .apk

Tags: android, meteor, apk, adt

I got an issue on exporting .apk file from Meteor 1.0.
I have already built the file with Meteor, and running on the simulator fine. But when I imported it to ADT, and trying to build the .apk for google play, it got run time errors.

[image: Runtime errors when linking the src folder]

Any Ideas?

Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class should be parameterized    ContentFilesystem.java  /liveitnode/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 53 Java Problem

Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class should be parameterized    HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java /liveitnode-CordovaLib/src/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http    line 174    Java Problem

Dead code   CordovaUriHelper.java   /liveitnode-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova   line 77 Java Problem

Dead code   CordovaUriHelper.java   /liveitnode-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova   line 77 Java Problem

Comment: Please include the errors (the Logcat output, in this case) as well as any associated code in a formatted code block; a low-resolution screenshot of the errors is not very helpful.

Comment: Thx @AdamS, there total 54 Warnings when building the app.
Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized ContentFilesystem.java /liveitnode/src/org/apache/cordova/file line 53 Java Problem
Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java /liveitnode-CordovaLib/src/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http line 174 Java Problem